# fetch the contents of a sibling div when clicking on the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html structures something like this:

```
<div id="result1" class="show ">
  <span id="sibA1" class="clickClass">a1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibA2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">a2</span>
</div>

<div id="result2" class="show ">
  <span id="sibB1" class="clickClass">b1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibB2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">b2</span>
</div>

<div id="result3" class="show ">
  <span id="sibC1" class="clickClass">c1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibC2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">c2</span>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is, when a user clicks on a span having `clickClass`, I have to fetch the text present inside the span with `cIdClass` lying near to it.

```
$(".clickClass").live("click", function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  var $name = $clicked.html();
  var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
  console.log("test: " + $(this).siblings(".cIdClass").eq(0).text());
});
```

**my jquery version is 1.10.2** and this code doesnot produce any results for that.

Comment: `.live` es deprecated for version `1.10.2`.Check console for errors..

Comment: use **.on** instead of **.live**

Comment: You want to set it's text to `cIdClass` ?

Comment: I just tested your code (replacing `.live` with `.on` though) and it works just fine... What's the problem you're having exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

Here we are grabbing the parent `div` with class `show` of currently clicked `span` and then looking for inner `span` tag with class `cIdClass` and reading its text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".clickClass").on("click", function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(this);
    var text = $clicked.closest(".show").find(".cIdClass").text();
    alert(text);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1" class="show ">
  <span id="sibA1" class="clickClass">a1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibA2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">a2</span>
</div>

<div id="result2" class="show ">
  <span id="sibB1" class="clickClass">b1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibB2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">b2</span>
</div>

<div id="result3" class="show ">
  <span id="sibC1" class="clickClass">c1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibC2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">c2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` event of the span retrieve its text using `text()` method then get it's parent `div` using `parent()` and finally find the sibling span with `find()` method using its classname. Once you find the sibling set the retrieved text as its text.

```js
$(".clickClass").click(function(){
  var text=$(this).text();
  $sibspan=$(this).parent().find('.cIdClass');
  $sibspan.text(text);
  $sibspan.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1" class="show ">
  <span id="sibA1" class="clickClass">a1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibA2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">a2</span>
</div>

<div id="result2" class="show ">
  <span id="sibB1" class="clickClass">b1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibB2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">b2</span>
</div>

<div id="result3" class="show ">
  <span id="sibC1" class="clickClass">c1</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="sibC2" class="cIdClass" style="display:none">c2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickClass").on("click", function() {
    var value = $(this).closest(".show").find(".cIdClass").text();
    alert(value);
  });
});
```